# Counting the number of same elements in an arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

So I'm creating an exam grading system which has a getExamScore(Student a, int examId) method. This method retrieves the answer key for the specified exam, a student's answer sheet for that exam and evaluates how many points the student got. This is a rough sketch of what it does.

```
Exam toIterate = database.get(examId);
    Map<Integer, Question> map = toIterate.getMap();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Question> entry : map.entrySet()){
        answerKey.add(entry.getAnswer());
        points.add(entry.getPoints());
    }
System.out.println(answerKey);
System.out.println(points);
//Outputs 
[False, True, False]
[2.0, 4.0, 3.0]
```

Now I have a seperate method somewhere that adds to an arraylist all of the student's answers for that exam.

```
Student s = new Student();
AnswerSheet as = s.getAnswerSheet(int examId);
ArrayList<String> studentAnswers = as.getAnswers(int examId);
System.out.println(studentAnswers);
//Ouputs
[False, True, False]
```

Now I want to compare the answerKey to studentAnswers and if the answers match up add the points from the points arrayList at the corresponding index to the overall score. I tried the following code and it works but it's a little bit of an ugly solution. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I'm open to suggestions to change my design as well. I just thought this would be the easiest way of doing this.

```
int i = 0;
    for(String s: studentAnswer){
                if(s.equals(answerKey.get(i))){
                    score += points.get(i);
                }
                i++;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your current design

```
answerKey.entrySet().stream()
    .mapToDouble(e -> e.getValue().equals(answers.get(e.getKey())) ? points.get(e.getKey()) : 0)
    .sum();
```

Using the Question map

```
questions.entrySet().stream()
    .mapToDouble(e -> e.getValue().getAnswer().equals(answers.get(e.getKey())) ? e.getValue().getPoints() : 0)
    .sum();
```

Changing `studentAnswers` to `Map<Integer, String>`

```
 studentAnswers.entrySet().stream()
     .mapToDouble(e -> answerKey.get(e.getKey()).equals(e.getValue()) ? points.get(e.getKey()) : 0)
     .sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the nuances of your code, it seems your approach is awkward, for example the `Map<Integer, Question>` is useless.

The most natural way to record which answer is correct for a question is a field in question for the correct answer, or to decouple use a `Map<Question, Answer>`, or if multiple choices are the "correct answer" then a `Set<Answer>` but it doesn't change this solution:

```
Map<Question, Answer> correct;
Map<Question, Answer> actual;

int total = actual.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().equals(correct.get(e.getKey()))
    .mapToInt(e -> e.getKey().getScore())
    .sum();
```